# How can I change a file before save in drupal 7 programmatically?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to upload a Audio File on drupal, then trim audio file and save it in sites/default/files/audio/.
I know how can I trim audio file.
Now I only want set my audio-trim-library in drupal when file is uploaded and not saved.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you know about drupal custom coding this may help you..
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7